# Is a boost::thread automatically removed from a boost::thread_group when it terminates?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

<sup>([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970818/whats-the-best-way-to-delete-boostthread-object-right-after-its-work-is-compl), though similar, didn't really answer my question.)</sup>

I've had [problems with my own "thread group" implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434762/why-might-this-thread-management-pattern-result-in-a-deadlock), and being no closer to solving or even identifying the issue, I'm looking into just using `boost::thread_grp`.

Now, from what [documentation I can find on the subject](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.threadgroup)<sup>1</sup>, I've always believed that thread objects — no matter the duration of their actual work — remain alive and a part of a thread group until the thread group is destroyed.

However, a cursory test seems to indicate that `boost::thread_group::size()` decreases on its own as threads do their work and terminate. That would imply that the thread objects themselves are being cleaned up for me, too.

Is this true? Can I rely on it?

```
#include <cassert>
#include <unistd.h>         // for sleep()
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

boost::mutex m;
unsigned int count = 0;

void func() {
   boost::mutex::scoped_lock l(m);
   count++;
}

int main()
{
   boost::thread_group grp;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < 300; i++)
      grp.create_thread(func());
   
   sleep(10);
   
   assert(count == 300);
   assert(grp.size() == 0);  // passes, in my tests
   
   // ^ Can I rely on that?
   //   Do I really have no thread objects eating up
   //     memory, at this point?
   
   grp.join_all();
   // ^ Then I guess this is doing nothing, in this case...
}
```

If it is, then my entire original `has_threads` implementation was just a broken clone and I've wasted my time. :)

<sup>And, yes, `assert` was a really poor choice for this snippet, since I guess it could lead to any unlikely-outstanding threads from butchering the memory under what used to be `count`? Anyway, never mind that.</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> - I'm stuck on Boost 1.40, but the documentation on the matter seems to be the same for more recent versions.

---

#### Update

[This thread](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/thread-group-removal-of-items-td2585545.html) is an example of where people are saying the opposite of what my testing has shown. It does also provide a decent solution if that's the case, though; it's nice that `thread_group` is totally thread-safe (though I'm not convinced that that `shared_ptr::get()` is thread-safe; what if the thread ends before the `shared_ptr::reset` has finished?). Do I need to employ this solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I misinterpreted the results of my test by not abstracting away the task scheduler that creates threads for me. In short, I was checking `size()` on the wrong `boost::thread_group`.

In fact, `boost::thread_group::size()` *doesn't* go down on its own as threads terminate, so I'll be using [an adapted version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/9431/have-i-thought-of-everything-in-this-wrapper-around-boostthread-group) of the solution provided in the forum post I linked to in the question update.